# Copying Data into another sheet when a condition is meet

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, office365

Does anyone have any idea of a solution or know if what i would like to happen is even possible. I am a complete computer novice and know nothing about ExcelVB, if that's the path to take.

I've a USB RFID scanner that when our members enter into the space, they tap in. This generates their unique individual membership number. 
Using VLOOKUP i have made cell B & C populate the name and company they work for. 
In Cell D, the now time and date generate.

the VLOOKUP for member name is: =VLOOKUP(A2,'Client Database'!$A:$B,2,FALSE) 
and the VLOOKUP for company name is: =VLOOKUP(B2,'Client Database'!$B:$C,2,FALSE)

**What I would like to happen is:** 
When their Individual number populates in cell A, i would then like the cells A,B,C & D of that row to be copied into their individual company sheet.

Where then i'll manually log them out and work out the time between: time in and time out.

The object is to be able to make it so when the member logs in it records the time and data, name and company name. 
Once Copied into their individual company Tab, the data will be totaled at the end of the month. Haveing it cell table format makes it a whole lot easier when sending to the relevant persons.

Basically what i am trying to do is create a system to automatically record the members details of when they enter.

(I'm just out of collage started working here and really just want to improve their system)

I have included a link to an example excel wookbook, i have replaced the names for company policy.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/3tcnjwyv6vlevrd/Member%20Help%20Test.xlsm?dl=0

if this is even possible or if anyone has any better ideas please let me know, any help is greatly appreciated.

Kindest New11

Comment: A lot is possible and I can think of a few ways where you can achieve what you have asked for, however, without any sample data is it hard to see which solution would work best for you. Please EDIT your question (do not reply to this comment) with sample data and include your VLOOKUP() formulas too. Then you should get the help you need.

Comment: What is the purpose of copying into the individual company sheets? Maybe alternatives like filtering or using a pivot table (maybe with slicers) accomplish what you are doing with the other sheets?

Comment: Het Kevin, thanks for your message. I've updated my question to reflect your imput. :) 
gns, not to sure. I'll have to experment with pivot tables on the weekend to see if it would suit. Do you know if using pivot tables there'll still be a way to have the data automally copied into the pivot when a members number pops up?